# How to enable CORS on Glassfish?

Tags: tomcat, glassfish, cross-domain

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) is a mechanism that enables cross-origin requests[[1]](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter). As you can see in the link [[1]](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter), It is easy to enable CORS in Apache Tomcat 7. Just a configuration in the file `web.xml`.

As i'm testing a service with Glassfish normally performed over Tomcat in order to decide a migration from Tomcat to Glassfish, i need to enable CORS on Glassfish.

so how?

I'm using Glassfish 3.0.1.